# Excel Range selection problem

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that select colors a group of 5 cells
So basically it goes:
clear, yellow, blue, clear, yellow, blue, ...

```
Sub ColorBanding()
Dim num As Integer
For i = 2 To 50
    Dim range As String
    range("A" + Str(i) + ":E" + Str(i)).Select
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ' Yellow
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    ElseIf i Mod 3 = 2 Then
        ' Blue
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm having trouble with this line:
"range("A" + Str(i) + ":E" + Str(i)).Select"

Example on evaluation for i = 2:
outputs: "A 2:E 2"
should be: "A2:E2"

The technical error I get is:
"Expected an array"

Is there a better way of doing this?
And is there a way to get this way to work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct syntax. Also don't select/activate anything as it only slows things down. What use is 'num'?

```
Sub test()
Dim num As Integer, MyRange As Range, i As Integer

For i = 2 To 50
    Set MyRange = Range("A" & i & ":E" & i)
    MsgBox MyRange.Address 'Delete this test line
    With MyRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior
     If (i Mod 3) = 0 Then
           'Yellow
           .Pattern = xlSolid
           .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           .Color = 65535
           .TintAndShade = 0
           .PatternTintAndShade = 0

     ElseIf i Mod 3 = 2 Then
           'Blue
           .Pattern = xlSolid
           .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
           .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
           .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry about that num was a leftover from when I was going to do manual incrementing with a while loop. I've since found the For loop syntax. Sorry for any confusion it may have caused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
Dim num As Integer
For i = 2 To 50
    Dim range As String
    range("A" + Str(i) + ":E" + Str(i)).Select
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
    Cells(1, 1).Select
```

1. Please put all dims at the top
2. dim range as string? what where you thinking, a range is a range. As in a lumb of cells on a worksheet.
3. `range` is a reserved word, don't use it as a variable name, use something like `MyRange` instead.
4. Objects (like `range`, `worksheet` etc..) can only be assigned in a `Set object = reference_to_other_object_of_the_same_type` statement, see below.
5. Cells(1,1) relative to what? The default object is `ActiveWorksheet` and `ActiveWorksheet.Cells(1,1)` is permanently fixed to cell "A1". MyRange.Cells(1,1) on the other hand can move around.
6. In VBA '&' concatenates strings, the '+' operator only works on numbers

Change it to:

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim MyRange as Range
Dim i as Integer

For i = 2 To 50
    Set MyRange = range("A" & Str(i) & ":E" & Str(i))
    MyRange.Select
    If (i Mod 3) = 0 Then
        MyRange.Cells(1, 1).Select
   ...
```

Haven't tested the code yet, but I'm pretty sure it is close.

Comment: 1. Totally right. I'll change that. 2. Totally right. I'll change that. My mistake. 3. Totally right. 
5. Sorry my mistake. I was in the middle of writing a method that selected each cell and changed the color individually. I figured I should ask online in case there was a way to select them as a group and change all the colors at once. Trying to make more readable code!

Comment: Set MyRange = range("A" + Str(i) + ":E" + Str(i)) is wrong syntax in VBA